# Is it possible to go to python method definition from a robot framework keyword?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, robotframework

I want to use the keyboard shortcut to go a python method from robot framework files. Is that possible?

Robot framework keyword:

```
Check something
    Given I have my scenario configured
    When I configure something
    Then Something else happens

Library  myClass.py
```

Python method on myClass.py:

```
from robot.api.deco import keyword

class myClass(object):
    @keyword('I configure something')
    def i_configure_something(self):
        self.configure()
```

I'll explain what I want using Gherkin :P

```
Given I am using VS Code to edit my files
When I highlight the keyword "I configure something"
And I press F12
Then I want it to open my python file and go directly to the method definition.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For VSCode, I use [Robot Framework Intellisense](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TomiTurtiainen.rf-intellisense).

Comment: What config should I use?

My settings:
    "rfLanguageServer.includePaths": [
        "**/*.robot",
        "**/*.rst",
        "**/*.py"
    ]
    "files.associations": {
        "*.rst": "robot",
        "*.robot": "robot"
    },

Comment: It should already have the configs you were hoping for, check "Goto definition" and "Find all references" sections in the documentation: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TomiTurtiainen.rf-intellisense#user-content-goto-definition

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. We use [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) with Intellibot plugin. It is the best solution I have found so far. In PyCharm we can go to a python method right from the keyword using  `Ctrl+B`

It can also be achieved using Eclipse with Red plugin but I don't know the shortcut for the same.

Answer (score 0):

I use Pycharm for over 2 years and i use the Plugins:

- Robot Framework Support
- IntelliBot @SeleniumLibrary Patched (wo work with selenium keywords also... since we change from Selenium2Library to SeleniumLibrary)